# Making login using arraylist from file java code?

Tags: java, arraylist, file-handling

I am currently working on a project assigned to me by my teacher where I need to login a user into my system using;
first the user register the data is stored in file using arraylist(MUST INCLUDE part of assignment) this part working fine the code for this i use is;

```
ArrayList<data> regUser = new ArrayList<data>();

public void regUser() {
    String regName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter User Name:");
    String regPass = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter User Password:");

    data p = new data(regName, regPass);
    regUser.add(p);

    for (int i = 0; i < regUser.size(); i++) {
        try {
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\outputFile.txt", true);
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(writer);
            pw.println(regUser.get(i));
            pw.close();
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found");
        }
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "User registered successfully");
}
```

Now the user has to login from the data in file in same way first data from file is entered in arraylist then it is matched with user entered data but im having issues;

```
public void login() {
    ArrayList<String> loginUser = new ArrayList<>();
    String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter User Name:");
    String password = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter User Password:");
    try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\outputFile.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String st;
        while ((st = br.readLine()) != null) {
            loginUser.add(st);
        }
        // System.out.println(loginUser); 
        br.close();
        fr.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < loginUser.size(); i++) {

        if (loginUser.get(0).equals(name) && loginUser.get(1).equals(password)) {// help need for find a condition here
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome to Rent A Car");
            return;
        }
    }       
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong login info please try again");
}
```

Im not that much expert in arraylist so if someone can guide me a bit will really appreciate thanks in advance
the data in my outputfile.txt is for now:
helo 123
test 456

Comment: Can you post the data class too ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are obtaining the line from the file correctly, but you have to split the parts of the line, in this case split by space character, so that you can obtain the username and the password of the user separately. First, You will probably want to have username and password on each line in your text file, so that you can extract exactly 1 username and 1 password per read line in your `while` loop, e.g. of `outputfile.txt`:

```
helo 123
test 456
```

We'll assume that this will always work as expected (=a line in the file will always contain only the username and password separated by a space character). In a serious project you definitely shouldn't assume that and you should use a data store of some kind.

You can then achieve the splitting of each line in your while loop like this:

```
String[] credentials = st.split(" ");
```

`credentials` will hold 2 elements, which will be the username and password (e.g. credentials[0] = "helo" and credentials[1] = "123").

You can then do the following in your `while` loop to add the credentials to the `ArrayList` and to then match the strings added to the list, whether they match:

```
public void login()
    {
        ArrayList<String> loginUser=new ArrayList<>();
        String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter User Name:");
        String password = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter User Password:");
        try {
            FileReader fr=new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\outputFile.txt");
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);
            String st;
            while ((st = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                // This changed
                String[] credentials = st.split(" ");
                for (String credential : credentials) {
                    loginUser.add(credential);
                }
            }
            br.close();
            fr.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("File not found");
        }

        // This for block changed
        for (int i = 0; (i + 1) < loginUser.size(); i += 2) {
            String uname = loginUser.get(i);
            String pass = loginUser.get(i + 1);
            if (uname.equals(name) && pass.equals(password)) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome to Rent A Car ");
                return;
            }
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong login info please try again");
    }
```

The above code assumes your username is the first set of characters in the file and the password the second set of characters in the file, where username and password are separated by a space characters. The `i` in the `for` loop increments by 2, because 0 = username, 1 = password; 3 = username, 4 = password etc. The `(i + 1) < loginUser.size();` is a precaution check to verify that there are next 2 elements (username and password).

It's a pretty nasty code with an `ArrayList`, but if it's a must for the assignment, then so be it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks you so much sir for your answer, It really helped a lot